# verifying signatures with openssl in linux

Tags: openssl

I use this command for encryption:

```
echo 'bla bla bla'|openssl dgst -sha256 -sign pki/A.key -out notifications/notification_1.signature
```

But when i try to decrypt with this command

```
dgst -verify A.pem -signature ../notifications/notification_1.signature text.txt
```

Show me the next error

unable to load key file

Anybody could help me, thanks

Comment: This is not about programming or development, and is not encryption or decryption either. Your `A.pem` needs to be a public key but either isn't or is improperly formatted -- look in the file to see what's in it. If it's not a public key, replace it by the public key (which you can extract from the private key file or a certificate file, if you have one). If it's improperly formatted, correct it.

Comment: It is properly formatted, I try wit .crt file and it show me the same error

Answer (score 0):

Generate your private and public keys:

```
openssl req -nodes -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout my.priv.key -out my.crt
```

Sign with private key:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -sign my.priv.key -out transaction.signature transaction.csv
echo 'Real important text'|openssl dgst -sha256 -sign my.priv.key -out important.signature
```

To hash the previous signature:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 transaction.signature
```

To verify with public key, the transaction previously signed:

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify <(openssl x509 -in my.crt -pubkey -noout) -signature transaction.signature transaction.csv
```